# How to select from specific Excel sheet in C#

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

I have this command in C#:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from[Sheet1$]", con);
```

And its working fine when sheet is called Sheet1, but in my case sheet has different name. How can I accomplish that ?

I already tried something like this:

```
string sheetName = "First sheet";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from["+sheetName+"$]", con);
```

Comment: Have you tried without "select * from["+sheetName +"]"?

Comment: Unless it's just a copy/paste error, you should have a space between `from` and `[`. -- `select * from ["+sheetName+"$]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to erase whitespace from sheet name, in example change:

```
string sheetName = "First sheet";
```

to

```
string sheetName = "FirstSheet";
```

You are not allowed to do whitespaces in SQL-based table's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with getting the sheet names right, you can try `GetOleDbSchemaTable()` to get the schema and pass this value to your `OleDbCommand`. Note that this works only if you now the positioning of your worksheet in the excel.

Hope this helps!

```
                objConn = new OleDbConnection(constring);
                objConn.Open();
                // Get the data table containg the schema guid.
                var dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                var query = "select * from [" + dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring + "");
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
                da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: apart from this, you can try enclosing sheet name in single quotes ['sheetName$']. This should take care of the space separated sheet names, such as "My excel sheet".